# Getting folder content in same project or dll thorough Reflection

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, directory-structure

#Get current Assembly information through Reflection.

```cs
protected static string GetCurrentFolder()
{
    string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
    string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Access folder after get the current assembly information.
- Add folder in the corresponding path first.

```cs
 var file = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(GetCurrentFolder(), @"Documents\Template.html"));
```

#Without Reflection you can use the below command,but make sure you copy the file in bin -> debug folder
Set the property of file Copy to Output Directory as **"Copy Always"** from visual studio.(Create a folder for your document as paste the file in visual studio)

```cs
File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Documents\Template.html"));
```